# IdentityServer4/IdentityServer3 Cross Applications Issue

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver3, identityserver4

I have two websites , website A and Web site B( both IdentityServer3 Clients).

I have a IdentityServer4 which authenticate both sites users and redirect them to corresponding website, Everything is working fine.

But I have an issue. these both sites users should not login to each other websites.

Users with application Id A  =>  WebSite A . It mean All user those should access site A which have  applicationId of website A in their records.

Users with application Id B  =>  WebSite B . It mean All user those should access site B which have  applicationId of website B in their records.

Right now If a user login in A , and in same browser I navigate to Site B, the same user without authentication get login into Site B.

How can I stop this behaviour.

Comment: Are you defining both website A and website B as the same clients, or different (ClientID)? Are you defining different scopes for these two clients?

Comment: How were you planning on defining the sets of users that could log into A and log into B?  The end result is (probably) that you end up with a claim for each website allowing you access, but there are lots of technical details in there.

Comment: Mashton -  Yes I am defining both websites as different clients. and different scopes.

Comment: I am using   .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()  command to configure Identity with IdentityServer4